# Success/failure callback not called from parse-mailgun api in cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mailgun

I am using mailgun service to send mails in my parse application. Mails are delivered successfully. When I try to print the response message, most of the time success/error function is not called. Is it common in cloud code?

```
Mailgun.sendEmail({
  to: "abc@xyz.com",
  from: from,
  "h:Reply-To": "test@test.com",
  subject: "Hi"
}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log("success"+httpResponse);
 },
 error: function(httpResponse) { 
      console.log(""error"+httpResponse);
}
```

});